# How to put Drawable image to int array .NB: Image is not in R.Drawable class

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I converted an image from BASE64 to imageByteArray the code is:

```
String imageBytes =item_image;
imageByteArray = Base64.decode(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

then I converted imageByteArray to Bitmap code is

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray,0, imageByteArray.length);
```

again I Converted that Bitmap image to Drawable code is below

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
```

So the Drawable image is inside the "d". These steps I do it for creating ViewPager in my application.

Anyone can help me to how to put this Drawable image to an Integer array.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have integer array of drawable?

What exactly you want to do?

If you are so obsessed in using array, then why don't you use `List`?

example:

```
List<Drawable> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
imageList.add(d);
//to get the item
Drawable image = imageList.get(i);
//where i is index of the item you want to get
```

Comment: Hi Atif, I wants to make a View pager actually.                                    private int[] offerImages = {
            R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3
    };     Wants the drawable image like this way it is possible?

Comment: Yea, you can use List for that purpose.